# Serialization: Can't find non-serializable component of desired serialized object

Tags: java, serialization, serializable, externalizable

I got an object which should be serialized. Atm I let it implement Serializable but in runtime I get an

```
Failed to marshal object with optimized marhshaller:{ $heresAhugeString$ }
Failed to serialize object: { $alsoHugeString$ } 
java.io.IOException: Externalizable class doesn't have default constructor: interface java.io.Externalizable 
Externalizable class doesn't have default constructor: interface java.io.Externalizable
java.io.Externalizable.<init>()
```

The last exception (java.io.Externalizable.() comes infinite times)
I try to find the non-serializable field but I only can see that it throws exception at serializing a ConcurrentHashMap. I know this aren't much information but the complete stacktrace is quite big. 
Any tips how to find out which field in the map is responsible for non-serialization ? Or which information should I add ? 
Regards

Comment: Shouldn't this help you - `Externalizable class doesn't have default constructor`

Comment: But I don't know which class is meant...

Comment: @Abubakkar is correct. When serializing, the default constructor is needed to instantiate the serialized class. You don't have one.

Comment: The exception doesn't 'come infinite times'. It comes once for every key or value in the map. Look at the end of the stack trace.

Comment: @EJP I think not. But could be possible. In the debugger there's a line cause = {NoSuchMethodException@129509} and it has got a child which has the same line and so on ... (the id is always the same)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what type of deserialization you are doing, but if you don't need use this field after unmarshalling, then you must set it as `transient`.

The `transient` java keyword can be used if your are use the Java Serialization, or `@Transient` if you are using JPA, or even `@JsonIgnoreProperties` if you are using Jackson